# Value Error: could not convert string to float: due to headers

Tags: python

Hi I have looked at many answers to this but I'm not sure what to do.  My code is looking at a list and I think when it hits the column headings, I get this error (ValueError)

but if I can get through the headings, I know it will work - Here's my code

```
your_price = [float(i.get_attribute('value')) for I in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@maxlength='23']")]
```

Suggestions?

Comment: In the code that you provided, on one side you are using a capital i, on the other a lower case i.

Answer (score 0):

// not sure how iterating your data is controlled. try to wrap each increment
 in a try/catch/finally - might gracefully skip the headers
try
   your_price = [float(i.get_attribute('value')) for I in
   driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@maxlength='23']")]
catch/except
   print value to log as a string data that caused the exception
end